# UITapGestureRecognizer doesn't work when lots of sprites touched fast enough

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have initialized UITapGesture as follows:

```
tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
```

As per code, if you tap on a sprite, it moves to new location using CCMoveTo action with duration = 0.3.
This works fine when a Sprite is tapped and you wait till it reaches new destination.
So far so good.

But if you tap on sprites fast enough to get an effect of multiple sprites moving to new destinations, I noticed some of the sprites are left inbetween and stop some random location.

Why this would be happening? Any thoughts?

Comment: most likely you don't stop the move action before running a new one, causing two move actions to run simultaneously on the same sprite

Comment: No, it not same sprite and even with stopAllActions on sprite before CCMoveTo action, I get same problem.